# Color reduction with ImageMagick

Tags: colors, imagemagick, color-space

There's an image I convert to grey in a first step using this:

```
convert out.jpg -colorspace GRAY -normalize png:out.png
```

In another step I would like to reduce colors to 12:

```
convert out.png +dither -colors 12 -filter box -normalize png:out.png
```

This works perfectly with a very old version of GraphicsMagick which I have installed on one machine. On another machine is the latest version of ImageMagick. Here the resulting image just has 8 colors.

Is there a way I can force ImageMagick to make exactly 12 colors? Not more, not less?

Comment: Did you check if your out.png file contains more than 8 colors?

Comment: yes, it does. the first out.png is exactly the same on both machines. but the color reduction not.

Comment: what are you expecting IM to do with an image that really only has 3 colours then?

Comment: Well, that'd be okay, but IF the source has more colors it should use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `-posterize` switch

`convert colors.png -colorspace gray +dither -posterize 12 mono12.png`

Answer (score 0):

You can create our own 12 color colorable image and use -remap to recolor your image. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#remap and use -dither none